# Not a number in header: Neo4j import tool

Tags: import, neo4j

I am trying to use the `Neo4j` `import` tool and ran into the following error:

[image]

Apparently it does not like my `tsne:X` header. It is very weird because I did not really change the structure of the dataset (except for adding two new columns: `DATASET` and `cellName`) that I am importing, and previously it was working just fine. The `cells.csv` looks like that:

[image]

I inspected the values in `tsneX:float` and `tsneY:float` columns, but they seem fine, they are float numbers. If there were some strings anywhere, I would expect `neo4j` to report the line number at least.

I am importing multiple similar files at the same time, like that:

> sudo neo4j-admin import --database=lanersson.db --nodes 
>       import/genes.csv --nodes 
>    "import/combined/c57bl6_p19/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_e165/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p0/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p18/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p23/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p5/cells.csv,import/combined/hgfapgfp_p120/cells.csv,import/combined/hgfapgfp_p132/cells.csv"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think that you need to give an example of a file with data on which you can repeat this error.

Comment: It is given above, `cells.csv`, or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, several lines of cells.csv on which this error would repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The error was happening because headers should be present only in the first file, and not in the next ones when we are importing multiple files at the same time, so changing this:

> sudo neo4j-admin import --database=lanersson.db --nodes import/genes.csv --nodes "import/combined/c57bl6_p19/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_e165/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p0/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p18/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p23/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p5/cells.csv,import/combined/hgfapgfp_p120/cells.csv,import/combined/hgfapgfp_p132/cells.csv"

to

> sudo neo4j-admin import --database=lanersson.db --nodes import/genes.csv --nodes import/combined/c57bl6_p19/cells.csv --nodes import/combined/cd1_e165/cells.csv,import/combined/cd1_p0/cells.csv --nodes import/combined/cd1_p18/cells.csv --nodes import/combined/cd1_p23/cells.csv --nodes import/combined/cd1_p5/cells.csv --nodes import/combined/hgfapgfp_p120/cells.csv --nodes import/combined/hgfapgfp_p132/cells.csv

Solved the issue. So, instead of importing multiple files, I am importing each one separately since each one of the `cells.csv` has its own header. It would be nice if `Neo4j` supplied a way of importing without the need to remove headers in all of the subsequent files since when we generate data output files, headers are present in all of the files.